# Write xy coordinates to .shp file Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, arcgis

I am using code in Matlab that writes xy coordinates and an associated z-value to a .txt file.  However, I have been converting these .txt files to .shp point files and matching .shp polygon files in ArcMap 10.  How could I update the attached code segment to output .shp files rather than .txt files so that I can skip a processing step?  Thanks in advance.

```
[flout] = strread(fileName, '%s', 'delimiter','.')
outfilename = [outputdir 'Coords_' char(flout(1)) '.txt'];
fid2 = fopen(outfilename, 'wt');
fprintf(fid2, 'x,y,z,\n');     % Adds x,y,z, as a header
fclose(fid2);
dlmwrite(outfilename,Listpos4,'-append','delimiter',',', 'precision', '%.5f');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to create three files, not just the .shp. There's also the index (.shx) and attributes (.dbf) files. The formats aren't that difficult ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) has the basic format for .shp/.shx) but they are all binary formats.

It might be easier to write a python script using ArcPy to import the .txt file and export it as .shp, rather than trying to write your own shapefile.